# MySQL match against with a slash

Tags: mysql, escaping, match, slash, against

I'm having some problems searching for products that contain a slash (for example ac/dc) with mysql's match against.

There seems to be a certain setting that's affecting this. On my windows' xammp with default settings each of these works great:

```
MATCH (content) AGAINST ('+ac/dc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and

```
MATCH (content) AGAINST ("+ac/dc*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and

```
MATCH (content) AGAINST ('"+ac/dc*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and

```
MATCH (content) AGAINST ("'+ac/dc*'" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and

```
MATCH (content) AGAINST ('+ac\/dc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But none of them work on our production server which is on a linux system (I don't know which distro but it's under plesk).

And what I mean by "don't work". The query returns 0 rows. The production server has ft_min_word as 2.

Comment: Just a long shot, maybe you can try setting the database charset (e.g. utf-8, or whatever it is) on the linux machine the same as on windows xampp. Another long shot :-) might be escaping the character on the linux machine, as such ...('"+ac//dc*"' IN...

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Both has utf-8. I am not receiving any errors. It just returns 0 rows.

Comment: Have you done an `analyze table` on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a server problem, to this day I still don't know how I could get it fixed, what I did was changed how the whole system works.

I have a search table where I store the search words, there I remove slashes so AC/DC becomes ACDC and on search I modify the query to remove the slash again so it tries to match ACDC and find's the correct row.

Comment: Try using a `%LIKE%` query instead (if you detect this special character). I don't see any other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the storage engine in both XAMP and production server. There are restrictions on fulltext search http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-restrictions.html. Also, the table definitions must match for fulltext search.

Slash isn't a special character, although double quotes is. So, `+ac/dc*` must give a different result set, than `"+ac/dc*"` for example.

Apart from that, the only difference, I can think of, would be different table contents.

Comment: They seem to be exactly the same, both as MyISAM and utf8_swedish_ci. For some reason the local version says fulltext index cardinality = 1 and the production server says it's 0. Though it works exactly the same if used with normal search words.